# subtract two column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 column in my database . column a column b column c.
I want subtract column a and b then input result in column c.
I use PHP and mysqli. if you have sample source I'm happy to introduce or advise how to write

Comment: tell us what you've tried and how you're stuck. fyi, people around here aren't code generator..

Comment: The task as it's described is essentially pointless. You have to explain, why do you think you need that at all

Comment: thanks for your guidance

Comment: Please provide some attempts which you have made in order for others to understand your doubts. If possible please provide with an example of what you want exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is super old, but since it was the top result I got, here's a way forward for anyone else that's looking: check out generated columns.

A decent tutorial is [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/), and a quick google will get you plenty more on the topic.

For the question asked, the benefit of a generated column is that the math being done (subtraction, in this case) is done automatically by the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
Insert into table_name (column_c)
select column_a - column_b from table_name;
```

Comment: $sub=mysqli_query("SELECT a-bFROM my_tbl");       now how insert this result into c column?

Answer (score 0):

First, subtract the first 2 columns by doing this query

```
SELECT (COUNT(COLUMN1) - COUNT(COLUMN2)) FROM TABLENAME;
```

After subtracting those columns, try using AS and name the 3rd column like this

```
SELECT (COUNT(COLUMN1) - COUNT(COLUMN2)) AS COLUMN3 FROM TABLENAME;
```

I hope this helps you somehow!